# The argument of char* converted to python to call a python function in C++ by boost.python

Tags: python, c++, boost-python

I call a python function in c++ by boost.python. And pass a argument of char* to the python function.But there was a error.
TypeError: NO to_python (by-value) converter found for c++ type: char.

The following is code:
C++

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/module.hpp>
#include <boost/def.hpp>
using namespace boost::python;

void foo(object obj) {
    char *aa="1234abcd";
    obj(aa);
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(ctopy)
{
    def("foo",foo);
}
```

python

```
import ctopy

def test(data)
    print data

t1=ctopy.foo(test)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `const char*`, especially when using string literals:

```
char* bad = "Foo"; // wrong!
bad[0] = 'f'; // undefined behavior!
```

Correct:

```
const char* s = "Foo"; // correct
obj(s); // automatically converted to python string
```

Alternatively you can use:

```
std::string s = "Bar"; // ok: std::string
obj(s); // automatically converted to python string

obj("Baz"); // ok: it's actually a const char*

char c = 'X'; // ok, single character
obj(c); // automatically converted to python string

signed char d = 42; // careful!
obj(d); // converted to integer (same for unsigned char)
```

`boost::python` defines string converters for `const char*`, `std::string` and `char` as well as `std::wstring` for Python3.
To select a proper converter, boost is trying to match the type through specialized templates (defined for built-in types) which defaults to a converter registry lookup if nothing fits. Since `char*` does not match `const char*`, an no converter for `char*` is registered,
the conversion fails.

If you have a proper `char*`, cast it to a `const char*` before passing it to python:

```
char* p = new char[4];
memcpy(p,"Foo",4); // include terminating '\0'
obj( const_cast<const char*>(p) );
delete [] p;
```

Comment: Good.Thank you.It seems that the official document without this help.