# boost python won't auto-convert char* data members

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

I'm trying to wrap a C++ api and I'm hitting a roadblock on some `char*` class members. It seems that boost-python will auto convert `char const *` and `std::string` types into python objects (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14029351/the-argument-of-char-converted-to-python-to-call-a-python-function-in-c-by-bo)), but it balks at `char*` types. This is the error I get (in python):

```
TypeError: No to_python (by-value) converter found for C++ type: char*
```

It turns out that these particular `char *` members probably should have been declared as `char const *` since the strings are never altered.

I'm new to boost-python so maybe there is an obvious answer, but I'm not having much luck googling this one.

Is there an easy way to tell boost-python to auto convert these `char*` members?
(Unfortunately I can't change the declarations of `char *` to `char const *` since the API I am wrapping is not under my control.)

**UPDATE**:

Ok so I think that I need to add a custom converter to handle the `char*` members. I started writing one:

```
/** to-python convert for char* */
struct c_char_p_to_python_str
{
    static PyObject* convert(char* s) {
        return incref(object(const_cast<const char*>(s)).ptr());
    }
};

// register the QString-to-python converter
to_python_converter<char*, c_char_p_to_python_str>();
```

Unfortunately this does not work. This is the error:

```
error: expected unqualified-id
to_python_converter<char*, c_char_p_to_python_str>();
                                                   ^
```

Looking at the [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/python/doc/v2/to_python_converter.html) I can see that the template args have this signature:

```
template <class T, class Conversion, bool convertion_has_get_pytype_member=false>
```

Since `char*` isn't a class I'm guessing that's why this didn't work. Anyone have some insight?

**UPDATE2:**

Nope. Turns out `to_python_converter` needs to get called inside of the `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE` call.

I got the `to_python_converter` working (with some modifications). I also wrote a function to convert form python and registered it with `converter::registry::push_back`. I can see my to_python code running, but the from_python code never seems to run.

Comment: Apparently [`const` is needed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14029351/the-argument-of-char-converted-to-python-to-call-a-python-function-in-c-by-bo). Also if you don't already use boost elsewhere, it might interest you to know that there is a lighter, more recent (c++11 and newer) project that implements the same functions (it's almost a fork): [pybind11](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11) where this "problem" might not exist/be solved.

Comment: @Silmathoron, pybind11 looks promising. I'll try it out.

Comment: How about exposing them through getter and setter functions that will adapt the type? The getters/setters can even be just free-standing functions, so you don't have to modify the classes.

Comment: @DanMašek I did play around with that with add_property. I was able to get the getter portion working, but I couldn't figure out how to do the setter function. Could you post an answer with a working example with a simple C++ class with a char* member and wrap it with getter/setter functions?

Comment: Thinking about this a little more, what do those `char*` members represent? Does the class own them (is it responsible for allocating/deallocating the memory? The behaviour of a getter is straightforward, but what exactly do you envision the setter doing? Overwrite the existing string/buffer as far as possible? Reallocate memory if necessary?

You mention the strings never get altered -- could this just be made a read-only property?

Comment: @DanMašek The class does own them. When I say that the strings are const, I mean that they never get modified in place. However, it is valid to assign a new char* to the member variable. So, effectively, they behave just like python strings. Immutable (e.g. stuff like: `char *s = "foo"; s[0] = 'F';` never happens), but re-assignable. Assignment from python should allocate a new char* and set the member variable with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume we're wrapping some third-party API, and set aside the awfulness of having those pointers exposed and mucking with them from the outside.

Here's a short proof of concept:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
namespace bp = boost::python;

class example
{
public:
    example()
    {
        text = new char[1];
        text[0] = '\0';
    }

    ~example()
    {
        delete[] text;
    }

public:
    char* text;

};

char const* get_example_text(example* e)
{
    return e->text;
}

void set_example_text(example* e, char const* new_text)
{
    delete[] e->text;

    size_t n(strlen(new_text));
    e->text = new char[n+1];
    strncpy(e->text, new_text, n);
    e->text[n] = '\0';
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(so02)
{
    bp::class_<example>("example")
        .add_property("text", &get_example_text, &set_example_text)
        ;
}
```

Class `example` owns `text`, and is responsible for managing the memory.

We provide an external getter and setter function. The getter is simple, it just provides read access to the string. The setter frees the old string, allocates new memory of appropriate size, and copies the data.

Here's a simple test in python interpreter:

```
>>> import so02
>>> e = so02.example()
>>> e.text
''
>>> e.text = "foobar"
>>> e.text
'foobar'
```

---

Notes:

- `set_example_text()` could perhaps take `std::string` or `bp::object` so that we have the lenght easily available, and potentially allow assignment from more than just strings.
- If there are many member variables to wrap and the getter/setter pattern is similar, generate the code using templates, or even just few macros.
- There may be a way to do this with the converters, I'll have a look into that tomorrow. However, as we're dealing with memory management here, i'd personally prefer to handle it this way, as it's much more obvious what's happening.

Comment: Thanks for the proof of concept. I'll play around with templates to make it more generic.

Answer (score 1):

This expands on Dan's answer. I wrote some macro definitions which generate lambda expressions. The benefits of this approach are that it is not tied to a particular type or member name.

In the API I am wrapping, I have a few hundred classes to wrap. This allows me to make a single macro call for every `char*` class member.

Here is a modified version of Dan's example code:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
namespace bp = boost::python;

#define ADD_PROPERTY(TYPE, ATTR) add_property(#ATTR, SET_CHAR_P(TYPE, ATTR), \
                                              GET_CHAR_P(TYPE, ATTR))

#define SET_CHAR_P(TYPE, ATTR) +[](const TYPE& e){                  \
                                   if (!e.ATTR) return "";          \
                                   return (const char*)e.ATTR;      \
                               }
#define GET_CHAR_P(TYPE, ATTR) +[](TYPE& e, char const* new_text){  \
                                   delete[] e.ATTR;                 \
                                   size_t n(strlen(new_text));      \
                                   e.ATTR = new char[n+1];          \
                                   strncpy(e.ATTR, new_text, n);    \
                                   e.ATTR[n] = '\0';                \
                               }

class example
{
public:
    example()
    {
        text = new char[1];
        text[0] = '\0';
    }

    ~example()
    {
        delete[] text;
    }

public:
    char* text;

};


BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(topics)
{
    bp::class_<example>("example")
        .ADD_PROPERTY(example, text);
}
```